# Запись даты и времени в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Из csv получил дату и время: `29-05-2015 13:56:22`. Дата и время находится в переменной `$val[0]`.

Когда запросом записываю это в бд, то записываются как `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. 
Как мне переформатировать мою дату в нормальный вариант, чтобы все записывалось корректно. Сам файл мне изменять нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('29-05-2015 13:56:22'))
```

[date()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php), [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php), [живой пример](http://ideone.com/hPkkZt).